# Binding to value of ObservableMap by key

Tags: java, javafx, binding

Does JavaFX have a binding type where i supply an observable map with a key and the computed value will always update as the key/value pair changes? Removing that key the key from the map will result to a `null` value, adding it back will track that value back.

I've been looking around the JavaDoc and found `MapProperty`, `MapBinding` and `ObservableMapValue`, but nothing seems to serve this purpose.

I've already designed my own variant, but would like to use a rather failsafe and tested version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do

```
someObjectProperty.bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(
    () -> myObservableMap.get(key), myObservableMap);
```

or, as @VGR points out in the comments

```
someObjectProperty.bind(Bindings.valueAt(someObservableMap, key));
```

Here is a SSCCE using the second approach:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableMap;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BindToObservableMap extends Application {

    private static final String[] keys = {"key1", "key2", "key3"};

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ObservableMap<String, String> map = FXCollections.observableHashMap();
        for (String k : keys) map.put(k, k.replaceAll("key", "value"));

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(5);
        grid.setVgap(5);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        for (int i = 0 ; i < keys.length; i++) {
            grid.add(new Label(keys[i]), 0, i);
            Label boundLabel = new Label();
            boundLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.valueAt(map, keys[i]));
            grid.add(boundLabel, 1, i);
        }

        ComboBox<String> keyCombo = new ComboBox<>();
        keyCombo.getItems().setAll(keys);
        TextField valueField = new TextField();
        Button update = new Button("Update");
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler = e -> {
            map.put(keyCombo.getValue(), valueField.getText());
            valueField.clear();
            keyCombo.requestFocus();
        };
        valueField.setOnAction(handler);
        update.setOnAction(handler);

        grid.addRow(keys.length, keyCombo, valueField);
        grid.add(update, 0, keys.length + 1);

        Scene scene = new Scene(grid);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't this cause extra overhead to recompute value on changes not related to that specific key? My solution attaches a listener and only invalidates if that key changed.

Comment: @MouseEvent It will only notify invalidation listeners when other elements of the list change: it will not notify change listeners (because the value hasn't changed). So your implementation (implementing `ObservableMap`?) is likely slightly more efficient as it saves lookup in a map, but the tradeoff for additional code complexity is likely not worth it, imho.

Comment: Wouldn’t `Bindings.valueAt` be a more appropriate?

Comment: @VGR Oh, even better. I didn't know there was an ObservableMap version of that method.

Comment: @James_D Can you explain why .put to overwrite existing values does not work with StringProperty with this method, but does work with Strings as per your example? On the other hand using a map string, stringproperty works if .put is NOT used but .get(key).setValue(newVal)? Fixing a binding issue by NOT using properties seems backwards.

Comment: @Rattenmann What are you observing? If you are observing the actual `StringProperty`s in the map, then the binding is notified when you call `set` on the `StringProperty`. If you are observing the actual map itself, then the binding is notified when you call `map.put()`.

Comment: @James_D i am copy pasting your example for this test since my program is a little too far ahead and complicated to be sure nothing else interferes. Just changed the Observable map string string to string stringproperty to match my own use case.